# Console output is in order, as in object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, console.log

I have an array object that I display in the console, but with changed keys. When opening this object in the console, the array that comes second in the object is shown first (It is sorted alphabetically), and then the first, how can I fix this and make them appear in the correct order? It is important to preserve the ability to expand arrays inside the object, so the implementation of output through a string will not work.

```
const resultMain = {
    mad: [1, 2, 3],
    led: [62, 73, 85, 96, 10],
};

const customConsoleOutput = {
    top: resultMain.mad,
    rest: resultMain.led,
};

console.log(customConsoleOutput);
```

Console output:

```
{top: Array(3), rest: Array(5)}
```

But, when object opened:

```
{top: Array(3), rest: Array(5)}
>rest: (5) [62, 73, 85, 96, 10]
>top: (3) [1, 2, 3]
>[[Prototype]]: Object
```

I need top to be the first output and rest to be the second output, I read about alphabetical sorting in browsers, and I didn't understand how to change it, the only thing I found is output via console.table, but that doesn't work for me.

Comment: Why does the order of the keys the console displays matter in your case (yes, in Chrome it shows them in alphabetical order, but that shouldn't matter to how your code operates)? What should matter to you is the order the keys in your object are iterated, which is in insertion order (in most engines, or those that are compliant with ES2020) for your particular string keys. If you need reliable iteration order, you can use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead.

Comment: I understand, it's just that I was given this task to make the output to the console correct, this code doesn't do anything, and they want to know from me how to implement the correct output

Comment: `how to implement the correct output` you can't, because *correct output* is purely subjective - since the order of keys in an object should never be relied upon. The fact that the properties are in alphabetical order makes it simple to find a particualr property when you may have hundreds ... the console is a tool, and alphabetical order makes sense in this tool

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does JavaScript guarantee object property order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You cannot do this by design. The values are sorted so you can find the one you need in objects with tens of properties

You'll need a Devtools Custom Formatter to format an object an another way

Answer (score 0):

The keys of JavaScript objects have a certain order internally, but this order is defined by the ECMAScript specification. According to this specification, an object's keys are stored in the order they were created, and their output to the console follows that order.

However, the important thing to note here is that most browser developer tools automatically sort the keys of objects alphabetically. This has nothing to do with the ECMAScript specification and is just a UI feature of the browser developer tools.

Therefore, it is difficult to fix this problem in the code itself. However, when printing to the console, you can get the desired result by separating the arrays and printing them.

Comment: This is almost accurate since numeric keys will always be first, and in numeric order - non-numeric keys are then in the order you stated `Object.keys(object)` shows the key "order" - of course, I will admit that order may also not actually be the *actual* order internally, but, key order in an object is after all irrelevant

Comment: I understand, I did it like this, but still not close to the ideal and I want to do as I described, but I can not imagine how to come to it.
function customConsoleOutput(obj) {
  console.log("{top:", obj.mad, ", rest:", obj.led, "}");
}

Comment: [ChatGPT is banned at SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned)